# How to properly set the server login code?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, passport-local

I'm trying to set up a login page using passport-local this way, but it wouldn't work:

node server side:

```
// mongoose
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
User.find({}).exec(function(err, collection){
    if(collection.length === 0) {
        User.create({identifiant: '123', motDePasse: '123'});
    }
});

// passport-local
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(identifiant, motDePasse, done) {
        console.log(identifiant); // It's not logging
        User.findOne({identifiant:identifiant}).exec(function(err, user) {
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        })
    }
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    if(user) {
        done(null, user._id);
    }
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({_id:id}).exec(function(err, user) {
        if(user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    })
});

// route
app.post('/connexion', function(req, res, next){
    var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
        if(err) {return next(err);}
        if(!user) {res.send({success: false});}
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if(err) {return next(err);}
            res.send({success: true, user: user});
        })
    });
    auth(req, res, next);
});
```

angular client:

```
app.controller('uAsideLoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, uIdentity, uNotifier){
    $scope.identity = uIdentity;
    $scope.signin = function(identifiant, motDePasse){
        $http.post('/connexion', {identifiant: identifiant, motDePasse: motDePasse}).then(function(res){
            if(res.data.success) {
                uIdentity.currentUser = res.data.user;
                uNotifier.success("Vous êtes maintenant connecté!");
            } else {
                uNotifier.error("L'identifiant ou le mot-de-passe est incorrecte.");
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Here is the mongodb's user row :

> { "_id" : ObjectId("53df7b3b769827786b32dafe"), "identifiant" : "123", "motDePasse" : "123", "__v" : 0 }

I think that it's comming from LocalStrategy. I'm not getting the result of the console.log.

Any brilliant idea, please?

What's wrong, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's not within the code you showed. My guess is that the parameters used in your request to `/connexion` (I assume it's a regular `form` with a `POST` method) are misnamed, because you set custom field names.

From Passport's official docs :

> By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, options are available to change the defaults.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'passwd'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...
  }
));
```

But your name rings a bell, didn't you ask a similar question yesterday, we helped you, and you deleted your post after that ?

Comment: Yup, but I have fixed that yesterday. That was another issue. After that I have updated my form. And get again the same error. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well you could have answered your own post instead of deleting it, it could help others...

Could you edit your post to show us your form's HTML ? And what exactly is the error you're talking about ?